# C++: function call expression with braced-init-list - does standard prescribe to ignore braces in a trivial case of a single element list?

Tags: c++, list-initialization

Consider the following example:

```
class X;

void f(const X &);

void g()
{
    X x;
    f({x});
}
```

Does standard require that an implementation ignored curly braces in that case? Without any optimization involved. If yes, than since which version?

On a first glance, it looks like by rules there should be a temporary created - completely unnecessary, of course, but still. Looking at [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) I cannot find anything relevant. `X` is not an aggregate here.

Both GCC and Clang, even with `-O0`, produce code without temporary created - even if an `X` copy constructor has observable side-effects and even if `X` has `X(std::initializer_list<X>)` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization of `X const &x` (the argument of `f`) in `f({x})` is list initialization in a copy initialization context, by [`[dcl.init]/15`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.init-15). Thus, we can drop the function and just ask what this means:

```
int main() {
    X x;
    X const &y = {x}; // still copy list initialization
}
```

Now, the first clause in `[dcl.init.list]` to apply to this is [`[dcl.init.list]/3.9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.init.list-3.9), which states that you basically just drop the braces.

> ... if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` [here `X const&`] is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); ....

`X const&` is in fact a reference type, but its referenced type `X const` is indeed related to the initializer's type, `X`, so the clause still applies. Now we just have

```
int main() {
    X x;
    X const &y = x; // (non-list/"plain") copy-initialization
}
```

and of course that doesn't call `X`'s constructor (by [`[dcl.init.ref]/5.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.init.ref-5.1)).

Note that the above quote appears slightly reworded on your cppreference page, too:

> ... (if `T` is not a class type), if the braced-init-list has only one element and either `T` isn't a reference type or is a reference type whose referenced type is same as or is a base class of the type of the element, `T` is direct-initialized (in direct-list-initialization) or copy-initialized (in copy-list-initialization), ....

Perhaps the "`T` isn't a reference type" or "`T` is not a class type" made this fly under the radar, but this is the clause you were looking for, since a) a reference type is indeed not a class type and b) the "or ..." in the preconditions makes it apply. Judging by the lack of versioning boxes, this behavior would be as old as list initialization itself: since C++11.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I've overlooked that part.